# How to iterate over all of the files and directories in a directory?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I'm trying to iterate over all of the files/directories in a directory. That includes also all of the hidden files (without `.` and `..`). From previous topic in Bash it was suggested to use:

```
for current in $1/$run_folder/{..?,.[!.],}*;
    echo current
done
```

I tried it in `tcsh` but it didn't work. How can I do it in `tcsh`?

Comment: Instinctively, I would suggest executing the loop with `-exec` from `find`... Do you have a reason to avoid `find`?

Comment: It should be a `tcsh` script with logic in the `for` loop (not just printing the `current`). so it will be long for `-exec`

Comment: Seeing as `-exec` can execute _arbitrary_ commands, that does not sound like restriction. As soon as you have a script that takes pathnames as command line arguments, you could execute it with `find "$1/$run_folder" -exec scriptname '{}' +`

Comment: I want the `for` loop to be part of that script. In a shell script - iterate over the files/dirs in given path and do logic (like moving, removing and editing stuff). I don't want to have another script that does the logic.

Comment: Find -exec and xargs were developed precisely to meet this need. Don't assume limitations that don't exist. You might also explain "didn't work" in more detail: no files, wrong files. threw error, dumped kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use `tcsh`, but you should be able to achieve what you want using the `globdot` option<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
>   globdot (+)
>            If  set,  wild-card glob patterns will match files and directo‐
>            ries beginning with `.' except for `.' and `..'
> ```

So

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set globdot

foreach current ($1:q/$run_folder:q/*)
  printf '%s\n' $current:q
end
```

Beware it errors out with a *No match* error if there's no non-hidden file in the directory.

That can be worked around by including a wildcard known to match along with `*`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set globdot

set files = (/de[v] $1:q/$run_folder:q/*)
shift files

foreach current ($files:q)
  printf '%s\n' $current:q
end
```

BTW, the correct syntax for `bash` would be:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for current in "$1/$run_folder"/*; do
  printf '%s\n' "$current"
done
```

You had forgotten the quotes around your expansions, that `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data, and that by default non-matching globs are left unintended. The `dotglob` option (equivalent of csh/tcsh/zsh's `globdot` option) avoids the need for those 3 different globs.

---

Notes:

1. The `(+)` indicates that the feature is *"not found in most csh(1) implementations (specifically, the 4.4BSD csh)"*